# New version of eosjs does not use chainId, How does it work?

Tags: transactions, eosjs, rpc, api

I have worked with both new and previous versions of `eosjs`. In the previous version I had to make a `config object` like this:

```
Eos = require('eosjs')

// Default configuration
config = {
  chainId: null, // 32 byte (64 char) hex string
  keyProvider: ['PrivateKeys...'], // WIF string or array of keys..
  httpEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
  expireInSeconds: 60,
  broadcast: true,
  verbose: false, // API activity
  sign: true
}

eos = Eos(config)
```

we would push our transactions like this:

```
eos.transaction(
  {
    // ...headers,
    // context_free_actions: [],
    actions: [
      {
        account: 'eosio.token',
        name: 'transfer',
        authorization: [{
          actor: 'inita',
          permission: 'active'
        }],
        data: {
          from: 'inita',
          to: 'initb',
          quantity: '7.0000 SYS',
          memo: ''
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  // config -- example: {broadcast: false, sign: true}
)
```

but in the new version we use the following:

```
const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } = require('eosjs');
const JsSignatureProvider = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');  // development only
const fetch = require('node-fetch');                            // node only; not needed in browsers
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('util');           // node only; native TextEncoder/Decoder
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('text-encoding'); 
const defaultPrivateKey = "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr"; // useraaaaaaaa
const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);
const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://127.0.0.1:8888', { fetch });
const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });
```

then we send our transction :

```
(async () => {
  const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'eosio.token',
      name: 'transfer',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        from: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        to: 'useraaaaaaab',
        quantity: '0.0001 SYS',
        memo: '',
      },
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  console.dir(result);
})();
```

Why don't we need `chainId` in the new version? If it uses `chainId`, how did it find it internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eosjs *does* require `chainId`, but if it isn't provided directly it will be retrieved from the host endpoint.

`Api` accepts `chainId` as an argument but if `chainId` isn't passed as an argument when the api is constructed, `Api` will fetch it from the host endpoint via `JsonRpc`.

`transact()` checks to see if `chainId` is set. If not, it calls `rpc.get_info()` which returns JSON from `<host provided to JsonRpc>/v1/chain/get_info` containing the `chain_id` property.

In [eosjs-api.ts](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/08b474e/src/eosjs-api.ts#L30):

```
/** in Api constructor */
public chainId: string;

/** in transact() function */
if (!this.chainId) {
   info = await this.rpc.get_info();
   this.chainId = info.chain_id;
}
```

[eosjs-jsonrpc.ts](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/08b474e8c25ccccf2701ca04268fa5149728baa1/src/eosjs-jsonrpc.ts):

```
/** `fetch()` prepends the path with the host provided to JsonRpc and returns JSON containing `chain_id` */
public async get_info(): Promise<GetInfoResult> {
    return await this.fetch("/v1/chain/get_info", {});
}
```